# Science fiction/fantasy short story: humans strap on wings to ascend a huge alien mountain

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the name of an old SF short story where humans strap on wings to attempt to ascend a huge alien mountain by riding/flying the prevailing winds. Probably 1980s but I read it when I was very young. It was part of an anthology.

Most humans who attempt to fly the mountain fail and die. To succeed you need to learn to trust the winds, yourself, and the winged alien guides. Of the 2 people attempting in the story, one tries to control the winds and dies by crashing into the mountain. The other lives and reaches the peak by becoming one with the fierce existing winds.

I think people tried to conquer the mountain because it's there: perhaps a rite of passage? This is on an alien world populated by winged hominids and humans who must strap artificial wings to their backs to attempt to fly the mountain.

Comment: Heinlein comes to mind, I don't remember story title, sorry.   Hang on, no! The one I'm thinking about had people flying in a cave on the Moon, sorry again

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is extremely terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Anything you can add will help: Why were they doing it? "Because it's there" or some other reason?

Comment: This kind of reminds me of "The Storms of Windhaven" by Lisa Tuttle and George R. R. Martin, but I haven't read the story in 40 years.

Comment: @DannyMcG The Heinlein story is "The Menace from Earth"

Answer (score 6):

I'm positive this is "[The Winds at Starmont](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71556)" (1973) by Terry Carr.

The story takes place on a planet named (by humans) Starmont; we don't find out what the natives (*wheest*) call it.  It has lower gravity than Earth, and more oxygen in the atmosphere; the combination allows humans to fly using a molecular-thin membrane attached to their harness, arms and legs.

The mountain is also called Starmont, although the wheest call it *Hirrkaleorashe*.  Mike and his friend Kelso try to fly it along with their guide Sakkoneesh.  The natives fly it, but not to conquer it; it is somewhat between a rite of passage and a religious experience, to see how high they can fly and if they can learn to hear the mountain singing.

On the first day the three land in a field partway up the mountain to rest, and shelter with a wheest family; the parents are proud of how high up the mountain they live, but although they might have been able to fly higher they couldn't do it *together* so this is where they stayed.

Kelso doesn't fully trust Sakkoneesh's guidance and when he gets in trouble he tries to fly *away* from the mountain, which puts him in a strong downdraft that throws him onto the rocks.  Mike trusts Sakkoneesh, and at a critical point hears the mountain and is able to fly above the level of storms.

The story ends with Mike and Sakkoneesh, having stopped to take stop and rest, realizing they are just a short distance below the summit, and spreading their wings to fly the final distance.

It's only been published in [3 anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71556), 2 in the U.S. and 2 in the U.K.  The most likely one is [*The Light at the End of the Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?43061) (1976).

[image: Cover of The Light at the End of the Universe]